# Live Video Streaming asp.net

Tags: asp.net, video-streaming

I've a scenario where there're two servers(server 1 & server 2). There's a web cam/CCTV cam(or of any kind) that feeds video to server 1. I assume the video feeding to the server 1 is easily done by the camera setup. This live video is now somehow sent to Server 2 which is eventually broadcast to the clients.

Now the thing is I actually need a lead to follow how to start with the whole thing and where does media server's role kick in(if it's actually needed). I don't have any idea whatsoever regarding the whole process and am having trouble making relevant searches. Any advise or help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need to build it by yourself, or can you use existing software?

Comment: I don't think using an existing software will be a good idea but it sure would be a good reference. Can you please provide a link or anything, I would really appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

is there any specific reason why 2 servers are involved ? You could easily stream video from server 1, where you get the camera feed.

You could either use a streaming media server (Like adobe media server) or use a standalone application like Windows Media Encoder to give out the live stream for users to view.

Does your server 1 have enough bandwidth to stream the video to multiple users ? If 100 people view your stream at 1 Mbps, you will be needing around 20Mbps bandwidth in your server at a minimum, else the video streams may suffer. If you cannot arrange that much bandwidth in your server, you will have to use a CDN hosted streaming server (There are  lot of service providers).

If only a few users will be viewing your stream simultaneously, it may be fine with your existing setup.

If you are following the two server setup as you mentioned, follow these steps to broadcast.

1. Set up Adobe media server (trial will do for upto 10 simultaneous connection streams) on server 2.
2. Install Adobe media encoder on server 1, where the video stream is available.
3. From server 1, push the video stream via adobe media encoder to server 2, (set up a publishing point first for live).
4. get the streaming link from AMS installed in server 2, which can be embedded into any compatible player (flowplayer or jwplayer), and put it in a webpage for public access.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually it's a gaming scenario. Server 1 is in a physical place where the real gaming is undergone. We've a Camera setup there. Server 2 however is our server where the web application is hosted and the games played by clients is the same game played in the physical gaming room. Ideally, the video of the real gaming is broadcasted to the clients in real time. My requirement for now is that I've to broadcast the real gaming to all the connected clients and i really am exploring my options for this whole picture

Comment: @user3126947, please follow my instructions with adobe media server, and see if your bandwidth is sufficient for your needs.